# How to turn multiple observables an observable that emits once when all the source observables complete?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I'm calling an API method (using Angular's `HttpClient` several times as part of a form submission. (It adds a thing into another thing and our backend guys flat out refused to give me a batch-add method. So I call it once for every item the user enters.) The code is something like this (using lodash for data massaging):

```
const items = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux'];
const result$: Observable[] = _.map(items, it => httpClient.post('/items', it));
```

I tried combining them using `forkJoin`:

```
forkJoin(result$).subscribe(resp => ..., err => ...);
```

But that revealed some sort of bug in the back-end where it throws when I do this for multiple items, but doesn't if I add them one-by-one. (Race condition I'm guessing.)

I tried getting around this by using concat() to make the client do the requests one-by-one:

```
concat(result$).subscribe(resp => ..., err => ...);
```

But that fires the subscription once for every source observable, I only want to know when they all complete (or don't.) How do I get the behaviour of forkJoin, except with the source observables not being subscribed to concurrently?

Comment: `concat(...).pipe(ignoreElements())` will either complete (but emit no values) or error.

Comment: @cartant - well, that at least pointed me in the right direction, now I know I can pass a `complete` callback to `subscribe()`

Comment: This reads like you already know the answer.

Comment: @StefanHanke - I’ll either answerify what I have or nule this question since it’s a pretty basic API thing and I also have an unrelated bug in the question code; I’ll decide after finishing this all-nighter and catching at least a little sleep

Comment: OT, but you should tell your backend guys that doing this one by one is not only a scaling issue (user needs to wait n times as long), but also an issue of transactionality (usually you want all to succeed or fail, not get an intermediate state) and atomicity (user leaves page mid-stream will execute only half the requests). Also, maybe if they don't give you the endpoint, they should at least fix that bug. Not serving an endpoint concurrently is outrageous. Your backend guys are wrong here, very wrong.

Comment: @IngoBürk you’re underestimating the obstinacy involved, and odds are I’d get told to use the endpoint that can replace the whole collection; which would be atomic but also building previous+new items on the frontend is onerous and sending 102 elements to the API to accomplish adding 2 to the 100 that were there is just plain silly

Answer (score 0):

You can use [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html)

> concatMap: it's maping values to inner observable, subscribe and emit
>   **in order**.

In your case `forkJoin` is doing all subscriptions at the same time, but `concatMap` should do them ***one by one***.

I hope this is useful to you

Comment: Sorry, no, concatMap still emits once for every time a source observable emits.

Comment: can ```skipUntil``` help you here? https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/skipUntil